# catch(err) giving error but do not return object data in async function in node express js

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, postman, try-catch

I'm using node v10.19.0 and i have created async function (req) {} it has try catch block if the error occur, then it console the error but cant return that error.

In routes.js: `router.post("/somefunction", middleware.somefunction);`

In middleware.js:

```
module.exports.somefunction = async (req, res) => { 
  var someFuncResponse = await service.someFunction(req) 
  res.send(someFuncResponse) 
}
```

In service.js:

```
module.exports.someFunction = async function (req) {

  try{

     //some code which gives error
     let response = { id:1 }
     return { status: true, data: response }

   }catch(error){

     // catches the error 
     let response = { id:2 }
     console.log(error) // get print correctly
     console.log(response) // get print correctly

     return { status: false, data: response } //not returning this

   }
}
```

when i am hit this api on postman, i am getting "Could not get response" message.[image]

also i am getting below msg on console:

```
(node:55009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:55009) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Show how you use this function in a route handler

Comment: @Anatoly
in routes.js: 
router.post("/somefunction", middleware.somefunction);

in middleware.js: 

module.exports.somefunction = async (req, res) => {
    var someFuncResponse = await service.someFunction(req)
    res.send(someFuncResponse)
}

in service.js: 

actual function written
module.exports.someFunction = async function (req) {definition}

Comment: Could you please add all of this to the question and with formatting )

Comment: @Anatoly done. please check.

Comment: Hmm. Try to wrap return value for both paths in `Promise.resolve`

Comment: @Anatoly can you plz let me know how to do that?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap return values with `Promise.resolve`:

```
module.exports.someFunction = async function (req) {

  try{

     //some code which gives error
     let response = { id:1 }
     return Promise.resolve({ status: true, data: response })

   }catch(error){

     // catches the error 
     let response = { id:2 }
     console.log(error) // get print correctly
     console.log(response) // get print correctly

     return Promise.resolve({ status: false, data: response }) //not returning this

   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a global route error handler registered in Express?